# I want to pass the _id as parameter in http get request in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

```
  productSelect(_id){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/productSelect', { headers: headers, search: _id }).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }
```

index.js (node)

```
router.get('/productSelect', (req, res, next) =>{
    let _id = req.query.search;
    console.log(_id);
    productSchema.aggregate([   
        { $lookup:
            {
                from: 'supplierschemas',
                localField: 'supplierId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'supplier'
            }
        },
        { $lookup:
            {
                from: 'brandschemas',
                localField: 'brandId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'brand'
            }
        },
        { $lookup:
            {
                from: 'categoryschemas',
                localField: 'categoryId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'category'
            }
        }

    ], (err, productSchema) =>{
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else res.json(productSchema);
    });
});
```

this code return 'unknown'. how to fix this? and how to add pass the parameter to aggregate? i want to modify the select tags option based on the users selection

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need `req.query.search` instead of `req.body.search`. From documentation

> **req.query**
>
> query string parameter in the route. If there is no query string, it
>   is the empty object, {}.This property is an object containing a property for each

Comment: still returns undefined

Comment: Looks like you need to add at `get(..)` not search but smtng like `let params=new HttpParams(); params.set("search",_id);` and replace your `{header:header,search:_id}` with `{header:header,params:params}`

Comment: how to inerpret the value when the node.js receives it?

Comment: As in proposed solution

Comment: @CharlesEdwinIson Did you try to add `params` on client side as in previous comment?